# Chebyshev Inequality in R

Tags: r

I have a statistical question in R and I was hoping to use Chebyshev inequality theorem, but I don't know how to implement it.

Example: Imagine a dataset with a nonnormal distribution, I need to be able to use Chebyshev's inequality theorem to assign NA values to any data point that falls within a certain lower bound of that distribution. For example, say the lower 5% of that distribution. This distribution is one-tailed with an absolute zero.

I am unfamiliar with how to go about this, as well as with what sort of example might help.

Comment: Although such methods have been invented (and even published), they are invalid.  The problem is that you only have a *sample* from a distribution.  Chebyshev's Inequality applies to the distribution--whose parameters you don't know--but it does not apply to the sample itself for making inferences about its parent distribution.  It no longer holds when you insert empirical "plug-in" estimates of the mean and standard deviation, either. If you're attempting to use this to identify and deal with outliers, then don't: it's a terrible procedure for that purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you collect call center wait times from a call center for 24 hours in a single day. Each hour, the mean and standard deviation of the call wait times will vary. Assume your call center is huge and you have 10,000 customer service representatives at any given hour.

Here are 24 data frames with 10,000 wait times per data frame. Each data frame was collected from a different hour on the same day.

```
set.seed(123)

mu <- rpois(24, 5)  # true mean call center wait times

mu

list.df <- lapply(mu, function(x) rpois(10000, x))  # 10k call center workers per hour

str(list.df)
```

Given 24 data frames, you can calculate the sample mean and sample standard deviation for each hour.

```
mean.each.hour <- sapply(list.df, mean)
sd.each.hour <- sapply(list.df, sd)

mean.each.hour
sd.each.hour
```

You could also calculate the 95th percentile of each hour

```
p95.each.hour <- sapply(list.df, function(x) quantile(x, probs = 0.95))
p95.each.hour
```

The question is: Are the observed 95th percentiles consistent with the theoretical relationship between the mean, standard deviation, percentiles? Assuming the sample mean and sample standard deviation are exactly equal to the population mean and population standard deviation.

We can use Chebyshev Inequality for this.

```
Chebyshev.k <- function(rt_prob=0.05){k = sqrt(1 / rt_prob)}

k <- Chebyshev.k(0.05)
k

Chebyshev.max <- function(means, stds, rt_probs){
  k <- Chebyshev.k(rt_probs)

  theoretical.max <- means + k*stds

  return(theoretical.max)
}

p95.theoretical <- Chebyshev.max(mean.each.hour, sd.each.hour, rt_probs=0.05)

p95.theoretical >= p95.each.hour
```

In our 24 data frames, each observed 95th percentile is less than or equal to the theoretical maximum given by Chebyshev Inequality.

Comment: The problem with this approach is that your assumption is extremely likely to be wrong: the sample mean and SD will *not* be the same as those of the population.  Thus, the Chebyshev inequality does not apply in the way you have assumed. Yes, you could argue that a large sample (plus some other assumptions) imply the same statistics will be close to the population stats.  But then why attempt to use Chebyshev when much better methods to identify outliers (or whatever the OP wants to do--it's not very clear) are available?